# I can't make a GET request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a table and a button under it. The button opens a form to fill in the data. I did it like this:

```
<!--Actually the button calling the form and the table-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mine_contract</title>
    <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mine_info">
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Full name of the director</th>
            <th>Phone number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>1</p></td>
            <td><p>1</p></td>
            <td><p>Example name</p></td>
            <td><p>Example address</p></td>
            <td><p>Full name director</p></td>
            <td><p>+00000000000</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup__container">
            <div class="popup__wrapper">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <form action="(I don't understand if there should be something here)" method="POST" class="form">
                    <button class="exit" class="exit" id="closeButton" onclick="delRow()">х</button>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="id">№:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="id" name="id" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="N_m">Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="N_m" name="n_m" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name_m"  required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Adr">Address:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Adr" name="Adr_m" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Full_name">Full name of the director:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Full_name" name="director" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Phone">Phone number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="Phone_number" placeholder="Например +00000000000" required>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" name = "submit" id="contact">Send to DB</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>       
    <button id="button" class="button" onclick="addRow()">Open the form</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I also wrote a script to open and close the POST request mandrel form when clicking on the "Send to DB" button.

```
//script.js
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const closeButton = document.querySelector('#closeButton');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.add('open');
  popup.classList.add('popup_open');
});

closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.remove('open');
  popup.classList.remove('popup_open');
});
form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://my_data:3000/mine_info/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    /*const request = await fetch('http://my_data:3000/mine_info/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    request: request.json(),
    })Attempt to make a GET request*/

  } catch (error) {
      
    // show some error message in the DOM
    console.log('err: ', error);
  }

  form.classList.remove('open');
  popup.classList.remove('popup_open');
});
```

I also have a backend, I made it like this:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: '',
  host: '',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  port: 5432,
})

const getMineinfo = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM mine_info', (error, results) => {
       if (error) {
         throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
     })
}

const createRow = (request, response) => {
    const { n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number } = request.body
  
    pool.query('INSERT INTO mine_info (n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.rows[0].id}`)
    })
  }

module.exports = {
    getMineinfo,
    createRow,
}//Variables from another file
```

```
//another file in which, there are these variables
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const db = require('./queries')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
 bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.use(cors())

app.get('/mine_info', db.getMineinfo)
app.post('/mine_info', db.createRow)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`
)})//it works I get the data in the form of JSON by reference http://my-data:3000/mine_info/
```

Why do I need a GET request in order to get my data that "weighs" on the link. But I don't understand how to place a GET request next to a POST (in my case, well, for example, is it not more correct to run the request immediately as soon as the page has loaded?). Maybe my attempt to make a GET request was correct, but I didn't understand that I needed to enter a loop there that would render new rows of the table?

I figured out how to make a POST request. And it works (writes information to the database). But I can't figure out what to do with the GET request (Please help me figure it out, this is the first project for me where I try my hand at both frontend and backend. Thank you for reading such a long question.

Answer (score -2):

`Why do I need a GET request`: Because you would want to show the rows in the table on load of the page, right?

1. Remove `action` attribute for the form, this will send request to same page (html5).
2. You can do the GET call on page load to render list of rows like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

// GET Request
// Load rows in the table element

});
```

Now how this should work is, after user submits the form, the page should do POST & reload and GET request will be called again so that table is loaded with expected data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).